# How do you represent BC dates in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the (best) way to handle dates before Christ in C#/.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877366/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-dates-before-christ-in-c-net)

In .NET how can I represent BC dates?  The DateTime struct only supports dates starting from 1 AD.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to look at noda-time which handles historic dates.  See http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/